# Passing large BLOBs to Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, coldfusion, blob

I have a simple (example) script to upload a file into the database (Oracle, if it matters):

```
<cfscript>
param string filename;

if ( FileExists( filename ) )
{
  result = new StoredProc(
    datasource = "ds",
    procedure  = "FILE_UPLOAD",
    result     = "NA",
    parameters = [
      { value = FileReadBinary( filename ), type = "in", cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_BLOB" }
    ]
  ).execute();
}
</cfscript>
```

However, the [ColdFusion CFML Reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/filereadbinary.html) states for `FileReadBinary( filepath )`:

> Note:
>   This action reads the file into a variable in the local Variables scope. It is not intended for use with large files, such as logs, because they can bring down the server.

If I should not use `FileReadBinary( filepath )`, how should I upload a large (0.5 - 1Tb) file?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading a file that large through a web interface anyway. The request will time out long before it gets uploaded. Doesn't matter how long you override the request timeout, this seems like it needs a different solution like uploading the file to an FTP server, outside of CF and having some other process load it into Oracle.

Comment: I agree it is not a typical usage, but won't surely fail. I am developing an application producing some hundred Mbytes answers for web requests, and it is working fine. Of course, the clients and the server are in the same LAN, but I suppose it is the same in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@Galcoholic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44163047/1509264), you can utilise the underlying Java classes and use [`CallableStatement.setBlob( int, InputStream )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,%20java.io.InputStream)):

```
<cfscript>
param string filename;

// Get the necessary Java classes:
Files = createObject( 'java', 'java.nio.file.Files' );
Paths = createObject( 'java', 'java.nio.file.Paths' );

// Do not timeout the request
setting requesttimeout = 0;

try {
  input = Files.newInputStream( Paths.get( filename, [] ), [] );

  connection  = createObject( 'java', 'coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory' )
                  .getDataSourceService()
                  .getDataSource( 'ds' )
                  .getConnection()
                  .getPhysicalConnection();
  statement   = connection.prepareCall( '{call FILE_UPLOAD(?)}' );
  statement.setBlob( JavaCast( 'int', 1 ), input );
  statement.executeUpdate()
}
finally
{
  if ( isDefined( "statement" ) )
    statement.close();
  if ( isDefined( "connection" ) )
    connection.close();
}
</cfscript>
```

Note:

- Every argument must be supplied for a Java method; so for methods with variable number of arguments then the `VARARGS` arguments must be passed as an array (or an empty array for no additional arguments).
- ColdFusion numeric values will not be implicitly coerced to Java numeric literals so `JavaCast( 'int', value )` is required.
- Error handling is not included in the above example.
- If the files have been uploaded then the "Maximum size of post data" and "Request Throttle Memory" settings in the Admin console will need to be increased from the default sizes to an appropriate limit for the size of the files being uploaded (otherwise `coldfusion.util.MemorySemaphore` will throw out-of-memory exceptions when it handles the upload before the script gets parsed).

Answer (score 1):

If using Java is an option, then you can pass an InputStream object to a PreparedStatement for filling a Blob field. Something like this, exception handling and all other stuff to be added:

```
Connection con = someDataSource.getConnection();
String sql = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(MY_BLOB) VALUES(?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyBigFile.big");
ps.setBlob(1, fis);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

I think Java will do it using buffers, and not load the whole file into memory.